# is this code true to query all documents in mongodb via mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

i'm using MongooseJS and doesn't return anything in console or res.json

is it about find function ?

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

var Panel = require("../models/Panel");

router.get("/panels", (req, res) => {
  Panel.find({}, function(err, panels) {
    if (err) res.send(err);

    console.log(panels);
    res.json(panels);
  });
});
```

This is the mongoose model for Panel section

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Panel = mongoose.model(
  "Panel",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    const: Number,
    salons: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Salon"
      }
    ]
  })
);

module.exports = Panel;
```

Comment: Are you sure you got records in the Panel collection?

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting this route? You can understand this by adding a `console.log("test")` befıre Panel.find()

Comment: @TamasSzoke yes, I'm sure,

Comment: @SuleymanSah I'm sure

Comment: Can you add code for `"../models/Panel"`?

Comment: @SuleymanSah added .

Comment: Everything looks correct, please be sure that you have documents in your panels collection. Check if you are looking at the db that the application uses.

Comment: Also change this `if (err) res.send(err);` line with `if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);`

Comment: @SuleymanSah I'm getting this err in connection : 
`Error MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 35.168.4.104:27017 closed`

Comment: `mongoose
  .connect(process.env.mongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`MongoDB connected ...`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error ${err}`);
  });`

Comment: and this is my connnection code

Comment: maybe it's because of VPN that i use?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, by catching errors, and trying to use anyone can access database, it was about my proxy :)